# Command line does not recognize python

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to download SimPy via pip but when I type "pip install simpy" my command line gives me this message : 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Then I tried typing "python" to check my Python version but it gave me the same message : 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your system has Python installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error and i fixed it by making sure python was on my path. an easy way of doing this is to re-install python and on the start up wizard right click the options and select'add to path'